# Rails jquery select by dynamic value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, dynamic

I'm using Ruby on Rails and I'm trying to hide/show an individual `div` from a collection of dynamically generated items by using the dynamically generated `id` which I then insert in a `data attribute`. This is what I've come up with so far, I think I'm on the right track but can't figure out what I'm missing. Without the `if statement` it works but shows the hidden div of every item instead of that specific one, and with the if statement, nothing happens.

**Link and hidden div**

```
<span class="options" data-ovly=<%= activity.targetable.id %>>
    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
</span>

<div class="ed_ovly none" data-ovly=<%= activity.targetable.id %>>
    <span class="shu_e">
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_medium_path(activity.targetable), :title => "Edit", :alt => "Edit", class: '' %>
    </span>
    <span class="shu_d">
        <%= render :partial => "activities/delete", :locals => {:activity => activity} %>
    </span>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$('.options').click(function(){
    var $ovly = $(this).attr("data-ovly");

    if ($('.ed_ovly').data("ovly") === $ovly) {
        $('.ed_ovly').toggleClass("none");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Use `id` attributes instead of `data-ovly` in your `div` tags and avoid the `if` statement in your script:

**html**

```
<span class="options" data-ovly=<%= activity.targetable.id %>>
  <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
</span>

<div class="ed_ovly none" id="<%= activity.targetable.id %>">
  <span class="shu_e">
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_medium_path(activity.targetable), :title => "Edit", :alt => "Edit", class: '' %>
  </span>
  <span class="shu_d">
    <%= render :partial => "activities/delete", :locals => {:activity => activity} %>
  </span>
</div>
```

**script**

```
$('.options').click(function() {
  var $ovly = $(this).data("ovly");
  $('#' + $ovly).toggleClass("none");
});
```

Check this snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.options').click(function() {
    var $ovly = $(this).data("ovly");
    $('#' + $ovly).toggleClass("none");
  });
});
```

```css
.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="options" data-ovly="1">
    ovly#1 <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
</span>
<br><br>
<span class="options" data-ovly="2">
    ovly#2 <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
</span>

<div class="ed_ovly none" id="1">
  <span class="shu_e">
    <a title="Edit ovly # 1" alt="Edit" href="#">Edit</a>
  </span>
  <span class="shu_d">
    "Your rendered partial for ovly # 1"
  </span>
</div>

<div class="ed_ovly none" id="2">
  <span class="shu_e">
    <a title="Edit ovly # 2" alt="Edit" href="#">Edit</a>
  </span>
  <span class="shu_d">
    "Your rendered partial for ovly # 2"
  </span>
</div>
```

---

#### Explanation

The first problem is in your `if` statement: You are using `===` to compare your values, but, since you are getting those values with different methods (`attr` and `data`), you are getting different data types.

Look closely at your code (i added a couple of comments):

```
$('.options').click(function(){
    var $ovly = $(this).attr("data-ovly");      // Returns a string: "1"

    if ($('.ed_ovly').data("ovly") === $ovly)   // Returns a number:  1
    {
        $('.ed_ovly').toggleClass("none");
    }
});
```

So your `if` returns `false` every time (since you are comparing `string` with `number`). To fix this, just use the same method<sup>1</sup> to get data in both lines, like this:

```
$('.options').click(function(){
    var $ovly = $(this).data("ovly");           // Returns a number: 1

    if ($('.ed_ovly').data("ovly") === $ovly)   // Returns a number: 1
    {
        $('.ed_ovly').toggleClass("none");
    }
});
```

Now that you are getting same data types, your `if` statement will work as expected. But you are not out of the woods yet, there is another issue with your code, look how you are identifying each *unique* `<div>`:

```
if ($('.ed_ovly').data("ovly") === $ovly)
{
    $('.ed_ovly').toggleClass("none");
}
```

You are using `$('.ed_ovly')`, that is, you are using the class, and all `div`s have that class, so with

```
$('.ed_ovly').data("ovly")
```

you will **always** get the value of the first `div` with class `ed_ovly`; and in

```
$('.ed_ovly').toggleClass("none")
```

you apply `toggleClasss("none")` to **all** `div`s with `ed_ovly` class (and, as a result, you will hide/show all `div`s every time).

So, you want to target only one `div` at a time, and the best way to do it is assigning an `id` to each `div` (also dynamically), something like this:

```
<div class="ed_ovly none" data-ovly="<%= activity.targetable.id %>" id="<%= activity.targetable.id %">
    <!-- Your div code... -->
</div>
```

And on your script, refer only to the `div` you want to show/hide using its `id`, and that can be done by changing `$('.ed_ovly')` to `$('#' + $ovly)`. Now your script should look like this:

```
if ($('#' + $ovly).data("ovly") === $ovly) {
    $('#' + $ovly).toggleClass("none");
}
```

Your script now should be working fine, but something is off: with the changes we made, now the `if` is not necessary at all! Since we now get a unique `id` for each div, its safe to delete it:

```
$('.options').click(function() {
    var $ovly = $(this).data("ovly");
    $('#' + $ovly).toggleClass("none");
});
```

And, while we are at it, lets get rid also of that unnecessary `data` tag in your `div` (i assume you don't need it for anything else):

```
<div class="ed_ovly none"  id="<%= activity.targetable.id %">
    <!-- Your div code... -->
</div>
```

**Note**

<sup>1</sup> You could still get away using both methods by comparing them with `==`, but i prefer sticking with `===`. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons) for more information.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, works perfectly. I understand much better now. Thanks!